# How to use an int from another class, change it and return changed ints in the original class

Tags: java, int

I'm making a really simple text turn based game, to make it readable I diceded to separate player's turn and enemy's into different classes, but that coused a lot of problems. Basically code goes like this:

Game itself, without not related stuff.

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int hp = 10, enemy_hp = 10;
    while (enemy_hp > 0 && hp > 0) {
        Player.main(args);
        Enemy.main(args);
            }
}
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hp, enemy_hp;
    enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 2;
    hp++;
    }
    }
```

Enemy class:

```
    public class Enemy{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hp, enemy_hp;
        hp = hp - 2;
        enemy_hp++;
        }
        }
```

How do I make Player class take int from Game class, Enemy take int from Player class, and then Game class take result and so on, while the loop is working?

Comment: You need to rethink your design. For starters, you should only have one `main` function in your whole program.

Comment: The code is really big and its hard even for me to read it now, that's why i dicided to do it this way.

Comment: Yes, breaking the code into pieces is the correct thing to do. But you need to understand how objects and methods work, what an "instance" is, what "state" is etc, in order to design it properly.

Comment: What you want to do is not difficult.  However as @RedRoboHood says, you really need to rethink your approach, starting with basic principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one golden rule when it comes to passing parameters in `Java`. Java is always `pass-by-value`. Both primitives and references are passed by value. The reason for sharing this information is that the way your currrent code is structured gives me a feeling that this is the next problem that you are going to run into.

Without spoon feeding you the code, here is a list of changes to consider

1. Don't use the `main` method as the interface between classes. `main` has special meaning. It is supposed to be the `entry` point of your standalone application. Only one class should ideally have a `main` method and this should be the `Game` class in your case.
2. Add an `int hp` field to both `Player` and `Enemy` classes.
3. Add mutator methods for the `hp` field in `Player` and `Enemy`. e.g `incrementHp`, `decrementHp`, `setHp` and `getHp`.
4. Add a method called `startGame` in `Game` class that can be called from `main`.
5. Inside the `startGame` method, create a new instance of `Player` using `Player player = new Player();`. Set the `hp` of the `Player` to `10` using `player.setHp(10)`;
6. Similarly, create a new `Enemy` object in `startGame` and set it's `hp`.
7. Whenever you want to increment the `hp` of a `Player` or `Enemy`, call the `incrementHp` method. Similarly, call the `decrementHp` method to decrement `hp`.

This is where my answer will end. This is where you get the general idea about how to proceed with further refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a primitive example of what [Chetan Kinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810077/chetan-kinger) has said.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player(100, 3);
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy(100, 4);
        while(player.isAlive() && enemy.isAlive())
        {
            enemy.takeDamage(player.damage);
            player.takeDamage(enemy.damage);
        }

        if(player.isAlive())
            System.out.println("Player won with " + player.getHp() + " left!");
        else if(enemy.isAlive())
            System.out.println("Enemy won with " + enemy.getHp() + " left!");
        else
            System.out.println("Draw!");

    }
}

public class Player
{
    int hp;
    int damage;

    public Player(int _hp, int _damage)
    {
        hp = _hp;
        damage = _damage;
    }

    public boolean isAlive()
    {
        return (this.hp > 0 ? true : false); 
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage)
    {
        this.hp -= damage; 
    }

    public int getHp()
    {
       return this.hp; 
    }
}

public class Enemy
{
    int hp;
    int damage;

    public Enemy(int _hp, int _damage)
    {
        hp = _hp;
        damage = _damage;
    }

    public boolean isAlive()
    {
        return (this.hp > 0 ? true : false); 
    }

    public void takeDamage(int damage)
    {
        this.hp -= damage; 
    }

    public int getHp()
    {
       return this.hp; 
    }
}
```

It is enough for you to get a general idea of what you should be doing from now on.